# Remove all but last similar key from array of objects

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, object, ecmascript-6

I have an array of objects. Many of the obk=jects have the same key. How do I remove all the objects from array that have the same key except the last one.

This is my array of objects:

```
[
 {d0: "abc"},
 {d0: "xyz"},
 {d1: "abc"},
 {d3: "xyz"},
 {d3: "abc"}
]
```

I only want the last occurrence of object by key in the array.

Essentially, I am looking for my array to look like this:

```
[
 {d0: "xyz"},
 {d1: "abc"},
 {d3: "abc"}
]
```

I am not sure how to go about this.

Comment: Flip it: keep the _first_ when _iterating backwards_. (This can also be done as simple reverse, take-first, reverse: no shortages for how to find/take first values. Often trivially implemented with a dictionary. In this specific case, might also want Object.keys()[0] to get the first/only key-as-value.)

Comment: @user2864740, Thank you for replying. But I am not sure what you mean by flip it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### If you want an Array:

You can use  a `reduceRight` function and a closure containing a `Set` object:

```
arr.reduceRight(((s = new Set()) => 
      (acc, obj, i) => s.has((key = Object.keys(obj)[0])) ? 
          acc : 
         ( s.add(key), acc.push(obj), acc )
 )(), []);
```

```js
let arr =[
 {d0: "abc"},
 {d0: "xyz"},
 {d1: "abc"},
 {d3: "xyz"},
 {d3: "abc"}
]

let result = arr.reduceRight(((s = new Set()) => 
          (acc, obj, i) => s.has((key = Object.keys(obj)[0])) ? 
              acc : 
             ( s.add(key), acc.push(obj), acc )
 )(), []);

console.log(result);
```

### If you just want a cumulative object:

You could use `Object.assign` combined with a `reduce` function

```
arr.reduce((acc,k) => (acc = Object.assign(acc, k)), {})
```

```js
let arr =[
 {d0: "abc"},
 {d0: "xyz"},
 {d1: "abc"},
 {d3: "xyz"},
 {d3: "abc"}
]

let result = arr.reduce((acc,k) => (acc = Object.assign(acc, k)), {});

console.log(result);
```

Probably a more performant way though is to iterate from the end of the list and escape if the key already exists using `reduceRight`

```
arr.reduceRight((acc,k) => acc[Object.keys(k)[0]] ? acc : ( acc = Object.assign(acc, k) ), {});
```

```js
    let arr =[
     {d0: "abc"},
     {d0: "xyz"},
     {d1: "abc"},
     {d3: "xyz"},
     {d3: "abc"}
    ]

let result = arr.reduceRight((acc,k,i) => acc[Object.keys(k)[0]] ? acc : ( acc = Object.assign(acc, k) ), {});

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Thank you for replying. But how do I make this objects inside the array? This just  forms an array. Can it be: [{},{},{}]

Comment: @nb_nb_nb oh, I see. Sure give me a moment

Answer (score 1):

you can use a reduce function and a tracker to track the item that you have seen. like this

```
  const arr = [{
      d0: "abc"
    },
    {
      d0: "xyz"
    },
    {
      d1: "abc"
    },
    {
      d3: "xyz"
    },
    {
      d3: "abc"
    }
  ]

  const tracker = {}

  result = arr.reduce((acc, cur) => {
    const key = Object.keys(cur)[0];
    if (tracker[key]) {
      tracker[key][key] = cur[key]
    } else {
      acc.push(cur);
      tracker[key] = cur;
    }
    return acc;
  }, []);

  console.log(result)
```

Comment: Can be done “exactly the same” without use of reduce as the approach relies on side-effects.